# How to implement more than one product identifier in app purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have two buttons open two new views after completing payment using a non consumable products (first_view and second_view), my code is working fine with one product but i don't know how i can use for more than one product this is my first experience with in app purchase coding. I think I need to update the productsRequest method which is below
i'm using this code :

```
implementation ViewController

@synthesize firstBTN, secondBTN,;

#define kStoredData @"first_view"

-(BOOL)IAPItemPurchased {



NSError *error = nil;
NSString *password = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:@"username" andServiceName:kStoredData error:&error];

if ([password isEqualToString:@"password"]) return YES; else return NO;

}


-(IBAction)firstBTNPressed:(id)sender {

if ([self IAPItemPurchased]) {

    firstViewController *controller = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstView" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];



[controller release];


} else {
    // not purchased so show a view to prompt for purchase
    askToPurchase = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Feature Locked" 
                        message:@"Purchase Feature?"
                        delegate:self 
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No", nil]; 
    askToPurchase.delegate = self;
    [askToPurchase show];
    [askToPurchase release];
}
}


-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:


            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                initWithTitle:@"Complete" 
                                message:@"You have unlocked Feature 2!"
                                delegate:self 
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil]; 
            [tmp show];
            [tmp release];


            NSError *error = nil;
            [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:@"username" andPassword:@"password" forServiceName:kStoredData updateExisting:YES error:&error];


            [firstBTN setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];



            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]  finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}


 -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:     (SKProductsResponse *)response
{

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];

if (count>0) {

validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"first_view"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

    }


else {
    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                        message:@"No products to purchase"
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [tmp show];
    [tmp release];
}


}


-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request  
{  
[request release];  
}  

-(void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error  
{  
NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);  
}  



#pragma mark AlertView Delegate
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (alertView==askToPurchase) {
    if (buttonIndex==0) {

        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) { 

            SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]  initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"first_view"]];  

            request.delegate = self;  
            [request start];  


        } else {
            UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                initWithTitle:@"Prohibited" 
                                message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a purchase!"
                                delegate:self 
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil]; 
            [tmp show];
            [tmp release];
        }
    }
}

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


if ([self IAPItemPurchased]) {
    [firstBTN setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

} else {
    [firstBTN setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Locked.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

}
```

can you please help me out to do same thing with my second button which opens a second view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first_view should be your product identifier how you have it in iTunes connect. just pass another product identifier for your other product. from the product request class you can figure out which product identifier was purchased.

let me know if this helps. (you should perhaps read some of the apple documentation on this, it is explained quite clearly)

Comment: So how can I update the product request class by using the product identifier (second_view) ? Thanks.

Comment: you could have another button in your alert view. you then have another if that responds to the right buttonindex. copy the code from the if and replace first view w second view. or put the logic elsewhere